Construct symbol for map onto itself
I would like to create a symbol denoting a map onto itself. Is there a way to only get the arrow tip from \leftarrow (to match the arrow head of e.g. \to) since \leftarrow is too long? The arrow head from the lasy fonts is unfortunately smaller as shown in this answer. Furthermore, the symbol is shifted slightly downwards. How can I align it correctly? Should I use \ooalign or array instead?
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\toitself}{\mathrel{\vcenter{\offinterlineskip\hbox{$\leftarrow$}\kern-0.63ex\hbox{$\supset$}}}}

\begin{document}
$f\colon D \toitself \supset \quad \toitself_{\toitself_{\toitself}} \supset_{\supset_{\supset}} \leftarrow_{\leftarrow_{\leftarrow}}$
\end{document}



You could use U+2b8c ⮌

@DavidCarlisle Thank you, that's great! Is there a latex math font including this character?

hmm it doesn't seem to be in most math fonts but is in the Segoe Windows symbol font so this works in windows with xelatex or lualatex  \documentclass{article} \usepackage{fontspec} \newfontfamily\sui{Segoe UI Symbol} \begin{document} $a \mathrel{\mbox{\sui⮌}} b$ \end{document}  output

@DavidCarlisle Thank you! It doesn't match the Computer Modern fonts but it's a nice alternative.

Yes when I  originally suggested that code point I thought it would be in at least some of the opentype math fonts but it seems not, just in the larger textual symbol fonts, so I think I'll leave the comment but not post an answer.

You can clip the arrow. Complications arise due to the peculiar bounding box of arrows in Computer Modern fonts.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\toitself}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\toitself@\relax}}

\newcommand{\toitself@}[2]{%
  \vbox{%
    \sbox\z@{$#1\supset$}
    \hbox{\clipbox{0 {-0.1\height} {0.65\width} {-0.4\height}}{$\m@th#1\leftarrow$}}
    \nointerlineskip
    \kern-0.57\ht\z@
    \ifx#1\scriptstyle\kern0.03\ht\z@\fi
    \ifx#1\scriptscriptstyle\kern0.04\ht\z@\fi
    \hbox{$\m@th#1\supset$}
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$f\colon D \toitself \supset$

$\scriptstyle\toitself \scriptscriptstyle\toitself$

\fboxsep=0pt \fboxrule=0.1pt
\fbox{$\toitself$}

{\large$\toitself$}

{\small$\toitself$}

{\footnotesize$\toitself$}

\end{document}



Thank you very much!

I think \makeatother at the end is missing.

@EuklidAlexandria Yes, fixed. Thanks for noting.

My solution uses pgf. You will be able to adjust the width of the horizontal lines, the height, the line width, the arrow type, or even the baseline.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newdimen\toitselfhlinewd
\newdimen\toitselfht

\def\toitself{
    \toitselfhlinewd=0.3em
    \toitselfht=0.5em
    \mathrel{
    \pgfpicture
    %\pgfsetbaseline{0pt}
    \pgfsetarrowsend{>}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\toitselfhlinewd}{0pt}}
    \pgfpatharc{-90}{90}{0.5\toitselfht}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\toitselfht}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \endpgfpicture
    }
}

\begin{document}
    $f\colon D \toitself F$
\end{document}



Thank you very much! The arrow head does not exactly match the Computer Modern one but I like the customizability.

You can add \pgfsetroundcap before \pgfusepath too ;)
